# Can't get my text value to work in my query

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method called populate_form in my user controller what this does is automatically grabs data from another table I have that will match with what they type in the emp_id text field ..  Example they type SMITHJ this value should be compared to my visual model and if it finds a match it will return their First name into the emp_first_name text field emp_first_name = John.

```
Clarification 
 visual model has a column called id
 user model has a column called emp_id 
 these are both the same so if the users emp_id = SMITHJ it will be visual id = SMITHJ
```

For some reason I cant get the data that is typed in the Emp_id text field to look at my visual model.

It keeps returning this..... why is it making it null?

```
Started GET "/user/populate_form&emp_id=SMITHJ" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-23 19:43:43 -0400
Processing by UserController#show as JSON
Parameters: {"id"=>"populate_form&emp_id=SMITHJ"}
Visual Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "EMPLOYEE".* FROM "EMPLOYEE"  WHERE "EMPLOYEE"."ID" IS NULL AND ROWNUM <= 1
```

This is my user controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController



 def populate_form
   @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])
   @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name

     render :json => {

        :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name
     }

   end
 end 


 def show
   @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])
   @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name

     render :json => {

        :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name
     }

   end
 end
```

This is my application js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#emp_id').change(function() {
        var url = "/user/populate_form&emp_id="+$(this).val();
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
          if(!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
          $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
        });
      }
    );
  });
```

And this is my view...

```
<div class='row form-group'>
   <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_id, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_id', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_first_name, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_first_name', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: change the url to `/user/populate_form?emp_id=SMITHJ` otherwise everything after `/user` is treated as your ID

Answer (score 1):

As @NekoNova suggested ----

change the url to /user/populate_form?emp_id=SMITHJ otherwise everything after /user is treated as your ID

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#emp_id').change(function() {
    var url = "/user/populate_form&emp_id?"+$(this).val();
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      if(!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
      $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
    });
  }
);
});
```

Once I did this it worked! Thanks again @NekoNova!